# Javascript issue: Const not running. Keeps sending emails

Tags: javascript

**Why does my app not run ''setVerzonden'' (Line 232) and doesn't change the spreadsheet cells to the correct values like it does in ''startRenders'' (Line 70)**

```
const {
    init,
    render
} = require('@nexrender/core');

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { gmail } = require('googleapis/build/src/apis/gmail');
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! But just pasting 270 lines of code and asking for debugging is not what stackoverflow is for. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [what to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
if (!item[4] || item[4] == "Rendered" && !item[5] || item[5] !== "Verzonden" && index !== 0)
```

This will evaluate to true whenever any of the conditions joined by || are true

What you probably meant is:

```
if ((!item[4] || item[4] == "Rendered") && (!item[5] || item[5] !== "Verzonden") && index !== 0)
```

This will evaluate to true only if all the conditions joined by && are true.